# combining word-wrap: break-word; and white-space: pre;

Tags: css

I display a piece of text taken from a text file in an HTML page, I want the new-lines in that text file to be taken into account so I am using "white-space: pre;". on the other hand, I want to prevent the text from overflowing outside its containing div, so I added "word-wrap: break-word;"
unfortunately, the two properties don't seem to work together (the white-space overrides the word-wrap). how can I make it so both properties work together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [*MDN doc page*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), this is the desired behavior for the `white-space` property:

> **pre**
>
> Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at <*br*> elements.
>
> **pre-wrap**
>
> Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at <*br*>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

So, to obtain what you described, you need to use the value `pre-wrap` in place of `pre`.